# How to redirect from pages without trailing slashes to pages with trailing slashes

Tags: sammy.js

I have sammy.js running in a knockout.js app.  I'm currently trying to redirect routes that are missing the trailing slash (for example `/#/stop/1/100032`) I would like to redirect all such pages missing the trailing slash, to the page with the trailing slash.

To complicate things, I would also like to have an error page in the case that there is no such route.

```
function RoutesViewModel () {
    var self = this;

    self.router = Sammy(function () {
        this.get('/#/stop/:agency_id/:stop_id/', function () {
            app.page.state('bus');
            app.stop.setCurrentById(this.params['agency_id'], this.params['stop_id']);
            mixpanel.track('stop page load', {
                'route': '/#/stop/' + this.params['agency_id'] + '/' + this.params['stop_id'] + '/',
            });
        });
        this.get('/(.*[^\/])', function () {
            this.redirect('/',this.params['splat'],'/');
        });
    });

    self.router.error = function (message, error) {
        app.page.header("Unable to find your page");
        app.page.message("The page you've requested could not be found.<br /><a href=\"/\">Click here</a> to return to the main page.");
    }

    self.run = function () {
        self.router.run();
    }
}
```

Above is a selection of the routes I have so far.  Unfortunately, when I go to the example url above, the page loads the error, instead of the correct `/#/stop/1/100032/`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I encountered this issue as well.

According to http://sammyjs.org/docs/routes routes are regular expressions. So this worked for me:

```
this.get('#/foo/:id/?', function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and decided to fix it with a catch-all at the end of my Sammy set-up.  My solution removes the trailing slash if there is one, but you could easily do the reverse, adding a slash on instead:

```
Sammy(function () {
    this.get('#', function () {
        // ...
    });
    this.notFound = function (method, path) {
        if (path[path.length - 1] === '/') {
            // remove trailing slash
            window.location = path.substring(0, path.length - 1);
        } else {
            // redirect to not found
        }
    }
});
```