# Sammy.js trailing slashes

Tags: sammy.js

I have this route:

```
this.get('/#week/:week', function() {...})
```

which works for `/#week/4` but not for `/#week/4/`

Any good ideas of how to leave the trailing slash optional in Sammy.js?
I'm now trying regex close to this:

```
this.get(/#week\/:week\/?/, function() {...})
```

but without any success.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877577/how-to-redirect-from-pages-without-trailing-slashes-to-pages-with-trailing-slash/32191048#32191048, though I can't yet mark it as duplicate since the other question hasn't an accepted answer either.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was too long time ago since I asked this. I couldn't possibly verify that answer works since I haven't touched Sammy in 2+ years... What do you normally do then? Accept the answer since it seems legit or do nothing?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Probably too late, but try replacing :week with something like this:

```
([^\/]*)
```

and then use

```
this.params['splat']
```

See http://sammyjs.org/docs/routes, search for Regexp. So your route would be:

```
this.get(/#week\/([^\/]*)\/?/, function() {
console.log(this.params['splat']);
})
```

Not sure exactly how you'd manage if you had multiple id's though...

Comment: Nevermind my last comment. this.params['splat'] is an array, so I imagine you can capture multiple ids. I haven't tried it yet, though.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to add `/?`, making your

`route:this.get('/#week/:week/?', function() {...})`